# closed function with uncountable set in the domain

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

First of all, I do apologize for the horrible title, but I really couldn't find a proper one :(.

I have to solve the following exercise:

Let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\wp(\mathbb{R})$ be a function such that $\forall x.(F(x)$ is closed and $x\notin F(x))$. Then there exists $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, card($A)=2^{\aleph_0}$ such that if $x\neq y$ in $A$ then $x\neq F(y)$ and $y\neq F(x)$.

Apart from the fact that I can't understand fully the reasons why it should be so, and neither am I convinced that the statement of the exercise should be true, I don't really know how to proceed.

I have also the following hint: $\forall x$ there exists an interval $I=(q_0,q_1)$ with $q_0,q_1\in \mathbb{Q}$, such that $x\in I$ and $I\cap F(x)=\emptyset$. But this is nothing really enlightening, I mean, it is just the topological definition of "a point not being in a closed set'', plus the fact that the rationals are dense in the real numbers.

I would be really grateful to anyone who can give my any sort of help.

Comment: I assume by $A\subseteq (R)$ you mean $A\subseteq\wp(\mathbb R)$. Is this the case? If so, what do you mean by $F(x)$ for $x\in A$? Is it $\bigcup_{r\in x}F(r)$? Or perhaps you meant to say that $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ and for $x\ne y$ in $A$ we have $x\notin F(y)$ and $y\notin F(x)$?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant to say the latter statement you wrote. In fact, it doesn't make any clear sense otherwise! Thank you for correcting me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view of the hint, I am assuming that the conclusion of the theorem was supposed to be:

> Then there exists $A\subseteq\Bbb R$, $|A|=2^{\aleph_0}$, such that if $x,y\in A$ and $x\ne y$, then $x\notin F(y)$ and $y\notin F(x)$.

Further HINT: For each $x\in\Bbb R$ let $I_x$ be an open interval with rational endpoints such that $x\in I_x$ and $I_x\cap F(x)=\varnothing$.

- If $I_x=I_y$, is $y$ in $F(x)$?

There are only countably many open intervals with rational endpoints, and $\Bbb R$ is not the union of countably many sets of cardinality less than $|\Bbb R|$.

Comment: @stemushu: You’re welcome. Take your time; if you get completely stuck, feel free to ask.

Comment: Excuse me, but now it seems obvious! I mean: clearly if I take $x, y \in  R$ such that $I_x= I_y$, then $x\notin F(y)$ and $y\notin F(x)$. But now, don't I know that the cardinality of every non-empty open set of $R$ is exactly the cardinality of $R$? So it suffices to take $A=I_x$ (which for sure exists non-empty), doesn't it?...it seems too immediate, where is the drawback in my reasoning? :(

Comment: @stemushu: Your reasoning is fine. I just realized that I was actually sketching the proof of a stronger statement: if $X\subseteq\Bbb R$, $|X|=|\Bbb R|$, and $F:X\to\wp(\Bbb R)$ is as in your theorem, then there is an $A\subseteq X$ that satisfies the conclusion of your theorem. But for $X=\Bbb R$ you can indeed just take $A$ to be $I_x$ for some $x$.

Comment: Wow I didn't think about something so easy! It has nothing to do with the stuff I am studying, so I can't understand why I was required to solve it...may I ask you why if $X\subseteq R$ then this is not as immediate as in case of $X=R$?

Comment: @stemushu: Because for a given $x\in X$ it might happen that $|I_x\cap X|<|\Bbb R|$. However, there has to be at least one $I_x$ such that $|I_x\cap X|=|\Bbb R|$.

Comment: Ok, this is totally clear to me now. Thank you very much for your help and your being patient and clarifying!

Comment: @stemushu: You’re very welcome!